# How do I get all the records in the view from foreach in controller?

Tags: php, codeigniter-3

I am using CodeIgniter, I am getting the member_id from the model and sending to the foreach to get the related data of the member_id.

```
$getMemberDetails['getAllMember']=$this->Member_model->getAllMember($member_id);//getting output is like 1,2,4,6,7

foreach ($getMemberDetails['getAllMember'] as $m_id) {
$getMemberDetails['getAllData']=$this->Member_model->getAllData($m_id->member_id);
    }

 $this->load->view('member/profile',$getMemberDetails);
```

foreach output is:(There are many columns I am just sharing an example)

```
Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [member_id] => 1 [first_name] => asdfgh ) ) 

Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [member_id] => 2 [first_name] => poiuyty ) )
```

After getting the output from the foreach I am sending to view to display the records.

In the view

```
<?php $post=$getAllData; 
    print_r($post);//here I am getting all the record?>
foreach($post as $key => $value)
{
    echo $value->first_name;
}
?>
```

How do I get all the records in the view? Would you help me out in this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are always overwriting the data with the last content, build an array of data and assign that instead...

```
$allData = [];
foreach ($getMemberDetails['getAllMember'] as $m_id) {
    $allData[] = $this->Member_model->getAllData($m_id->member_id)[0];
}
$getMemberDetails['getAllData'] = $allData;
```

I'm assuming `getAllData()` is returning an array of matching records, so even though there is only 1 record it will still return an array. Using `[0]` means to extract the 1 record your expecting.

Comment: I am getting the output also I am getting the error on View. I am display the data individual so I tried <?php $post=$getAllData; foreach ($post as $sec) {echo $sec->first_name; } and I got error "Message: Trying to get property of non-object". Should I use foreach ?

Comment: Always try `print_r()` if you get this sort of error, it helps to see what you are getting in `$sec`.  `foreach` is probably the best option, but see what the output gives you.

Comment: Looking at  the sample output above, you may need `echo $sec[0]->first_name;`

Comment: Let me try again. Give me some time to check

Comment: If I remove your controller code then it's working but getting the last record in the view. If I use your controller code then I am getting that error in the view.

Comment: Have you tried the `print_r($sec);` to see what is output.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185644/discussion-between-user9437856-and-nigel-ren).

Comment: I hope you are doing well, I know it's not a good way to redirect any member to the question but trust me I am solving one issue from the last 4 days. if you know any think on this please let me know. here is the link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61977036/how-to-display-the-array-inside-array-output

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `[]` this in your code.

```
    foreach ($getMemberDetails['getAllMember'] as $m_id) {
    $getMemberDetails['getAllData'][] = $this->Member_model->getAllData($m_id->member_id);
        }
```

In your view file you can access this array using below code.

```
$allData = $getAllData;

foreach($allData as $key => $value)
{
    echo $value->first_name;
}
```

Comment: I am getting the output also I am getting the error on View. I am display the data individual so I tried <?php $post=$getAllData;  foreach ($post as $sec) {echo $sec->first_name; } and I got error "Message: Trying to get property of non-object".  Should I use foreach ?

Comment: @user9437856 I have edited my code. hope it will help you.

Comment: I tried same but still getting the error. Message: Trying to get property of non-object

Comment: If I remove the []  form the controller then I am getting it but getting only last records